# suppose that the line $\Gamma=\{t+it:t\in \Bbb R\}$ is mapped to itself, If $f(\sqrt2 )=3$, then what is $f(\sqrt 2i)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be analytic on $\mathbb C$ and suppose that the line $\Gamma=\{t+it:t\in \Bbb R\}$ is mapped to itself, that is, $f(z)\in\Gamma$ for all $z \in \Gamma$. If $f(\sqrt2 )=3$, then what is $f(\sqrt 2i)$?

My question is should $\sqrt2$ be the form of $t+it$? since it belongs to $\Gamma$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I just don't see why $\sqrt 2$ is in $\Gamma$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes, my bad.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: But "$f(z)\in\Gamma$ for all $z\in\Gamma$" alone doesn't guarantee that it has that form. For example this is also true for $f(z)=(1-i)z^2$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You're right. I hadn't thought about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the reflection of $\sqrt{2}$ w.r.t $\Gamma$ is $\sqrt{2}i$ , because $\sqrt{2} \mapsto 3$, by the symmetry principle, $\sqrt{2}i \mapsto 3i$(reflection of $3$ w.r.t $\Gamma$) because $f(\Gamma)=\Gamma $.

about your comment, $f(z)$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{C}$, it is not defined only on $\Gamma$ , all the question says is that *in particular* it maps $\Gamma$ to itself.